# How to populate MySQL table data into React card components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have managed to populate a React table within a card (1st code snippet below) with MySQL table data but I don't know how to populate a card's information with the same SQL data.

The screenshot below shows how the cards are laid out using dummy data, and there should be N number of cards for N number of rows in the SQL table.

```
const Marketplace = (props) => {
  const marketplace = useSelector((state) => state.marketplace);

  const { classes, marketplaceData, ...rest } = props;
  let content = <div></div>;

  content = (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />

      <div>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                alt="Model Image"
                height="200"
                image={img}
                title="Model Image"
              />
              <CardContent>
              <Table
              {...rest}
              className={clsx(classes.root, classes)}
              tableHeaderColor="info"
              tableHead={[
                'Alg Name',
                'Author',
                'Animals',
                'Alg description',
                'Data',
              ]}
              tableData={marketplace.marketplaceData.map((marketplace) => {
                return [
                  marketplace['alg_name'],
                  marketplace['author'],
                  marketplace['classes'],
                  marketplace['alg_description'],
                  marketplace['alg_type'],
                ];
              })}
            />
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardBody>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data:</p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Demo Model
              </Button>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Download Model
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          
          </Card>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </div>
```

The code above shows a card with the working table that successfully pulls in and populates with SQL data.

The Code snippet below is the card using dummy data, but I don't know how to add a similar .map() property to populate the various texts and information at different points.

```
<div>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                alt="Model Image"
                height="200"
                image={img}
                title="Model Image"
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                  Model Name
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                  Model Description
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardBody>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data:</p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Demo Model
              </Button>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Download Model
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          
          </Card>
          </GridItem>
```

Having 4+ of the code segments above shows what the page should look like with dummy data. I am wondering how to automatically generate the right number of cards for the same number of data table rows without hard coding each card.
[image]

I have tried the following code below to add the SQL data to a table, but it just fills up in one card and looks very messy (code snippet and screenshot below)

```
<div>
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            alt="Model Image"
            height="200"
            image={img}
            title="Model Image"
          />
          <CardContent>
          {marketplace.marketplaceData.map((marketplace) => {
            return [
              marketplace['alg_name'],
              marketplace['author'],
              marketplace['classes'],
              marketplace['alg_description'],
              marketplace['alg_type'],
            ];
          })}
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {marketplace['alg_name']}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {marketplace['alg_description']}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardBody>
        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author: {marketplace['author']}</p>
        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals: {marketplace['classes']}</p>
        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data: {marketplace['alg_type']}</p>
        </CardBody>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Demo Model
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Download Model
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      
      </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  </div>
```

[image]

UPDATE: adding edits from @Linda Paiste. I have created two additional components and `MarketplaceGrid` is called in the `ModelMarketplace.js` file to display the grid of cards. Each file is in it's own snippet below, but at the moment I'm getting NULL root property error (screenshot below code snippets). I'm not sure if this is an error in my JS/React code or the SQL database.

Snippet 1: MarketplaceGrid.js

```
const MarketplaceGrid = ({ classes }) => {
    const marketplaceData = useSelector(
      (state) => state.marketplace.marketplaceData
    );
  
    return (
        <GridContainer>
          {marketplaceData.map((marketplace, i) => (
            <GridItem xs={1} sm={2} md={3} key={i}>
              <MarketplaceCard
                classes={classes}
                {...marketplace} //pass down all properties of marketplace as props
              />
            </GridItem>
          ))}
        </GridContainer>
    );
  };
  
  export default MarketplaceGrid;
```

Snippet 2: MarketplaceCard.js

```
import img from '../../images/Gorilla1.png';

const MarketplaceCard = ({ classes, author, alg_name, alg_description, alg_type}) => {
    return (
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            alt="Model Image"
            height="200"
            image={img}
            title="Model Image"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author: {author}</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals: {classes}</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data: {alg_type}</p>
            <p>{alg_description}</p>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Demo Model
            </Button>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Download Model
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    );
  };
  
  export default MarketplaceCard;
```

Snippet 3: ModelMarketplace.js

```
const Marketplace = (props) => {
  return (
    <main className={classes.content} >
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />

        <MarketplaceGrid />

    </main>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Marketplace);
```

Error screenshot: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null` in `marketplaceCard.js`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want (at least) two separate components here.  `MarketplaceCard` takes the values from a single row of the database and formats it into a complete card.   `MarketplaceGrid` loops through all of the rows and passes the data from each one to a `MarketplaceCard` component.

What you are doing here with `Table` is just confusion on your part and you don't want that at all.  You aren't making a table.

Don't assign your JSX to the variable `content`.  Just return it.

You want something roughly like this:

```
const MarketplaceGrid = ({ classes }) => {
  //select an array of marketplaces
  const marketplaceData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.marketplace.marketplaceData
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <GridContainer>
        {marketplaceData.map((marketplace, i) => (
          <GridItem xs={1} sm={2} md={3} key={i}>
            <MarketplaceCard
              classes={classes}
              {...marketplace} //pass down all properties of marketplace as props
            />
          </GridItem>
        ))}
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

const MarketplaceCard = ({ img, classes, author, alg_name, alg_description, alg_type}) => {
  // you need an image from somewhere
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt="Model Image"
          height="200"
          image={img}
          title="Model Image"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author: {author}</p>
          <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals: {alg_type}</p>
          <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data:</p>
          <p>{alg_description}</p>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Demo Model
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Download Model
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Linda, I'll give this solution a go if the one above doesn't work for me, cheers!

Comment: Would you split up MarketplaceCard and MarketplaceGrid into separate component files, and import them into a Markeplace page?

Comment: That would be a good design, yes. The way it's written in my answer is seems like `MarketplaceGrid` basically is the whole page, since it has `<div className={classes.content}>` and `<div className={classes.toolbar} />`, so you would move those out of `MarketplaceGrid` and into the parent `Marketplace` page.  You could either move the `useSelector` up and pass down the `marketplaceData` or keep it where it is.

Comment: The general idea behind writing flexible and reusable code is that this `MarketplaceCard` component doesn't depend on the Marketplace page.  It just depends on the props that it's given.  So you could potentially include a `MarketplaceCard` on any other page of your app.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was thinking. I'll give this solution a go for the rets of my day and let you know how things go. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Slowly getting there, I added the two new components and call the grid in ModelMarketplace.js, but am seeing an error that I haven't been able to debug. I've updated the original post with new code snippets and a screenshot of the error if you have any suggestions (not sure if it's a JS issue or coming from the SQL database with NULL entries in rows). Thanks again

Comment: Ok so the variable `classes` is `null` and not an object.  A quick way to suppress this is to default to an empty object if you don't get a value.    You could add defaults for everything. `const MarketplaceCard = ({ img = "", classes = {}, author = "", alg_name = "", alg_description = "", alg_type = ""})`.  But when you have a missing variable, figure out where it is supposed to come from and why it isn't there. `classes` is expected to be passed as a prop to `MarketplaceGrid` and passed down from there to `MarketplaceCard`.  But in  `Marketplace` you call `MarketplaceGrid` without that prop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223889/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-henrik).

Answer (score 2):

You're off to a good start here, but with your current code, the outcome is the expected result.

.map() will return a copy of an array, so you'll need to return a react element from your map function.

in the parent element:

```
data.map((marketplace) => {
  return (
      <CardElement prop1={marketplace.attribute1} prop2={marketplace.attribute2}/>
  )
})
```

The first step would be to export your `<Card>` element and set it up to take in props (you're off to a great start so far) so that it will display the data you're getting from the database.

The issue you're facing is where to call .map, and what to return from it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html here are some nice examples of how to use .map to return a component. I suggest starting with displaying multiple card elements with 1 unique attribute from your database. Once that it solved, it is just a matter of formatting the same pattern.

Edit: This entire card component can be refactored such that it reads its tabledata values from props.

```
const MarketplaceCard = (props) => {
  const marketplace = useSelector((state) => state.marketplace);

  const { classes, marketplaceData, ...rest } = props;
  let content = <div></div>;

  content = (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />

      <div>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                alt="Model Image"
                height="200"
                image={img}
                title="Model Image"
              />
              <CardContent>
              <Table
              {...rest}
              className={clsx(classes.root, classes)}
              tableHeaderColor="info"
              tableHead={[
                'Alg Name',
                'Author',
                'Animals',
                'Alg description',
                'Data',
              ]}
              tableData={{
              algName: props.name,
              author: props.author,
              classes: props.classes,
              description: props.description,
              type: props.type
              }}
            />
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardBody>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Author:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Animals:</p>
            <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Data:</p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Demo Model
              </Button>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Download Model
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          
          </Card>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </div>
```

export it to be used in another component

```
export default MarketPlaceCard
```

in a parent component, you can then call

```
{data.map((marketplace) => {
  return (
      <CardElement name={marketplace['alg_name']} author={marketplace['alg_author']} classes={marketplace['classes']} description={marketplace['alg_description']} type={marketplace['alg_type']}/>
  )
})}
```

This map function will return an array of JSX card components populated with the values from your array.

Comment: Amazing, I'm going to work through this advice tomorrow and see where I get. Will keep this page updated with progress, cheers!

Comment: Hi @magic-onion, I'm sorry but I've not had much luck trying to implement your solution but I think it's just my lack of experience. Do you mind elaborating on how this pieces into my code snippet? Much appreciated!